# PHP - is using multi_curl for parallel processing a good idea?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, parallel-processing

I needed parallel processing in PHP, but PHP doesn't support it without installing extensions, so I'm using `multi_curl` to achieve this.

`main.php` - Builds an array of urls, which are all `process.php` with different $_GET parameters. Then executes them all using multi_curl.

`process.php` - The processing logic for each thread.

I'd just like to know if this is a viable way of doing things. Is this retarded? Does it cause a lot of overhead? Is there a more sensible way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Ever heard of [forking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)?

Comment: @Orbling That's the extension I'm referring to. But I don't want to install extras, plus I haven't heard very good things about it.

Comment: Forking is elementary to multi-process execution on most systems.  Just people do not often use it in PHP, partly because PHP programmers are not used to the concept and the caveats.  There are plenty of gotchas doing it with PHP, but with careful handling it is a standard and sound method of splitting a process up.  Using curl has high overhead in most cases, but has the advantage of going through your webserver, so could load balance over machines, etc.

Comment: PHP is not overly well tailored for concurrency, and by extension, parallel processing.  Might be better dropping the work to Erlang, if you are generating an internal request anyway.  Unless there is a large body of library code that can not be quickly ported.

Comment: +1 sounds a perfectly good way to go about things, just make sure each "thread" isn't tripping over the others by hogging resources or locking tables... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Threading for PHP ...

Enjoy ...

To install in unix, you'll need a Thread Safe version of PHP. Most distros do not package this version so you'll have to build it yourself.

A quick description of how to do so would be:

```
cd /usr/src
wget  http://php.net/get/php-5.3.17.tar.bz2/from/us.php.net/mirror
tar -xf php-5.3.17.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.17/ext
wget https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tarball/master -O pthreads.tar.gz
tar -xf pthreads.tar.gz
mv krakjoe-pthreads* pthreads
cd ../
./buildconf --force
./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

I'd start with that, to build an isolated copy --prefix with a private location, like --prefix=/home/mydir, or some distros have a /usr/src/debug which is a good place for that sort of thing. You'll obviously want to add --with-mysql and the like, but how you do that depends on your system ( hint, you can use php -i | grep configure > factory.config to save your current php installations configure line and base your custom build of that knowing that any libaries it complains aren't available are an apt-get|yum install away ).

Comment: That's interesting. How do you install something like this though?

Comment: assuming you're on unix then and can't use the download... I'll post separate because it won't let me format it properly and I want it to be readable ...

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's a viable way of doing things in general, that's why the functionality exists.

As always, the devil is in the details. Multiple concurrent requests will contest with other processes for and consume server resources; you will want to regulate the degree of concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind that PHP does not support multi-processing by any reasonable means, multi_curl seems to be a good solution in your case!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP on a webserver (and multi_curl may be unavailable), one way (without libraries) to make it run scripts in parallel is to open sockets to localhost:80 and manually make the webserver run the scripts you want. They will run in parallel using the server multithreading. Then in a loop you collect all the results, and when all of them are done (or after a timeout of your choice) you go on.

This is a piece of code taken from a script that retrieves sizes of all images referenced on a webpage..

The get_img_size.php script retrieves the size and info of one image.

$sockets[] is an array that keeps one socket for every image to test.

```
        foreach($metaItems['items'] as $uCnt=>$uVal) {
            $metaItem=ContentLoader::splitOneNew($metaItems,$uCnt);
            $AnImage=$metaItem['url'];

            $sockets[$AnImage] = fsockopen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if(!$sockets[$AnImage]) {
                echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
            } else {
                $pathToRetriever=dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/tools/get_img_size.php?url='.rawurlencode($AnImage);
                // echo('<div>META Retrieving '.$pathToRetriever.' on server '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</div>');
                $out = "GET $pathToRetriever HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                $out .= "Host: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."\r\n";
                $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
                // echo($out);
                fwrite($sockets[$AnImage], $out);
                fflush($sockets[$AnImage]);
                // echo("<div>Socket open for $AnImage...</div>");
                // flush();
            }
        }
    }  else $FoundImagePaths2[]=$metaItems; // ALL of them urls belongs to us
```

After this you can do your own business while the "threads" go on working, then, in a loop, you go on reading from all $sockets[] and testing for EOF. In the example, much later in the code (a loop for each $AnImage):

```
            if(isset($sockets[$AnImage])) {
                if(feof($sockets[$AnImage])) {
                    if(!isset($sizes[$AnImage])) $sizes[$AnImage]='';
                    $sizes[$AnImage].=fgets($sockets[$AnImage], 4096);

                    // echo("<div>HTML $AnImage DONE.</div>");
                    // echo("<div>[ ".$sizes[$AnImage]." ]</div>");
                    // flush();
                    fclose($sockets[$AnImage]);
                    unset($sockets[$AnImage]);

                    $mysizes=ContentLoader::cleanResponse($sizes[$AnImage]);

                    // echo($sizes[$AnImage]." ");
                    // echo(ContentLoader::cleanResponse($sizes[$AnImage]));

                    if(!is_array($mysizes)) {continue;}

                    if($mysizes[0]>64 && $mysizes[1]>64 && ($mysizes[0]>128 || $mysizes[1]>128))
                        $FoundImagePaths2[]=array('kind'=>'image','url'=>$AnImage,'ext'=>$ext,'width'=>$mysizes[0],'height'=>$mysizes[1],'mime'=>$mysizes['mime']);
```

It is not efficient in terms of memory and processes and speed-wise, but if a single image takes a few seconds, the whole page with 20+ images takes the same few seconds to test them all. It's somehow parallel PHP, after all.